# How to change speed of podcast playback on iPad running iOS 5's Music app?

Tags: ipad, ios

It seems the option to enable double, normal, or half speed playback is gone from the Music app on iPads running iOS 5.

Anyone ran into this? Workarounds?

Comment: This was an surprising change that I don't see mentioned anywhere. Also missing it the ability to tell which chapter of a audio book you are on.

Comment: I removed all podcasts and audiobooks - synced - re-added podcasts and audiobooks - synced again - the playback speed issue and echo's continue on my iPad2. I tried a reset as well - didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the speed controls are available in iOS 5.1. They just are not there in 5.0.

Comment: This works for me too. Both in portrait and landscape mode.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I knew the answer. Mine has defaulted to half speed. :(

I do have a workaround you might be interested in though. After muh searching, I found an app called SpeedUp Player, which lets you set a playback speed between 0.5x and 2.5x. It's not perfect, but it does the job as a temporary fix.

Comment: Yep, I also ended up getting SpeedUp Player (the Pro version) and that's what I'm using right now to play podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had this issue myself, but several of my listeners have mentioned it. Has anyone tried removing the podcasts in question from syncing in iTunes and then reenabling it so the files are removed from and then copied back on to the device?

Comment: New podcast that arrive still have this issue. I have an iPad 1, might be related with that?

Answer (score 0):

For the audiobook and/or podcast in question, open up it's information box and click the "Options" button. In this section make sure the "Media Kind" is set to eiter "Audiobook" or "Podcast". iTunes relies solely on this paramater to know what playback features will be available for the media file in question. Playback speed options are **only** enabled for items marked as either of these two categories.

Updated: Here's a screen capture of my iPad running iOS 5.1
[image]

Comment: Media Kind is set. Playback buttons are not visible in OS 5.0.x.

Comment: Any reason why you are not running iOS 5.1?

Comment: Also just to clarify, was the Media Kind already set or did you just update them? If you just updated them, it will not take effect on your iPad until your next synch.

Comment: Already set, and jailbreak.

Comment: iOS 5.1 has a jailbreak. Here's a link to tutorials on how to do so. This link will show you all the tutorials covering the different iPad generations and computer OSes. You select the tutorial that would apply to your setup. I can only assume something odd happened when you installed your your jailbroken image of iOS 5.0.1 that may have caused this odd behavior. The speed playback feature has never been removed from any version of iOS for iPad or iPhone since it's introduction. So you're only option at this point is to restore your iPad with a new jailbroken iOS 5.1 image.

Comment: No link provide. Also, are you *sure* about 5.0 iPad having the buttons? I've found many comments elsewhere saying they don't exist on that version.

Comment: Positive. Current iPad user under iOS 5.1. Even verified before jumping into this thread. Here's the link, my apologies http://www.iclarified.com/entries/index.php?caid=2&scid=30&seid=16

Comment: Just updated my post with a screen capture of my iPad on iOS 5.1

Comment: Oh sorry... I have iPad 2. There is no jailbreak yet for 5.1 on iPad 2. Also, your screenshot is 5.1, and I know the controls exist in 5.1. I was seeking evidence of your comment that they exist in 5.0 and that my jailbreak is the issue, which I doubt.

Comment: Got it. Well I cannot recall having this issue prior to iOS 5.1 but all internet searches prove otherwise so I'm going to assume that I have been mistaken and suffering from blurred memory; so my bad on that. Ultimately, it seems there is no solution available for you outside of updating to iOS 5.1 or downgrading to iOS 4.3.3